# Shared Object Library not linked after compiling

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, linker-errors

My program uses the libuvc-library and therefore the libuvc.so.0.

But after successful compilation, i can't run the program, because:

```
root@Raspi_DataHarvest:~/Schreibtisch# g++ UVCCameraHandler.cpp `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs --cflags libuvc` -o UVCCameraHandler.o

./UVCCameraHandler.o: error while loading shared libraries: libuvc.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The reason is:

```
root@Raspi_DataHarvest:~/Schreibtisch# ldd UVCCameraHandler.o
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x7edff000)
        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so (0x76f1a000)
        libopencv_dnn.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.4 (0x76bc7000)
        libopencv_ml.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so.3.4 (0x76b20000)
******  libuvc.so.0 => not found  *******
...
```

The file is located in: **/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libuvc.so.0.0.6**

But I don't know how to link the .so file ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the run-time loader where to find your library, because this is not a normal path.

Use this command to run:

LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ./a.out

Or you can export this `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as a environment variable, and run `./a.out` directly afterwards.